# Não consigo instalar o TensorFlow-GPU

Tags: python, importação, machine-learning, aprendizagem-de-máquina, tensorflow

Comecei a aprender sobre o tensorflow recentemente e decidir trocar pela versao GPU, por ser muito mais rapido, mas não consigo, sempre da o mesmo erro.

Specs:

> - I5-8400
> - GTX 1060 6GB
> - Windows 10 Home 64x
> - 8GB RAM

.

Tentativas:

> - Tentei instalar pelo pip, python 3.6.8, cuda 10 e o cudnn mais recente para cuda 10
> - Tentei reinstalar o python junto a todos os componentes (CUDA e CuDnn)
> - Instalei o Visual Studio e reinstalei o CUDA e cuDnn
> - Tentei instalar o Anaconda mais recente, criei um env "padrao" e outro no python 3.6, pip install tensorflow-gpu em ambos

Todas as tentativas deram no mesmo erro, erro ao importar alguma DLL

Aqui esta o erro:
https://pastebin.com/KMEsZAmq

E aqui o codigo completo:
https://pastebin.com/7tS0Rd5S

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente você está instalando a versão mais atual do Tensorflow (talvez seja algum problema de compatibilidade, etc), uma opção é realizar a instalação de uma versão mais antiga:

Desinstale a versão atual, você fazer isso pelo pip:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu
```

Em sequência:

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.9 #Troque o numero para a versao desejada
```

Particularmente eu utilizo a 1.9, mas fica a seu critério e testes;
Também pode ser feito testes com outras versões do python.

**EDIT:**

Talvez seja necessário realizar um downgrade no Cuda para a versão 9.0.

Espero que seja uma solução para o seu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Tentando diminuir ao maximo qualquer problema utilizando o TensorFlow eu fiz uma "especie de check list", vamos lá então:

1. Biblioteca Cuda na versão 10 ou 10.1.
2. TensorFlow e/ou TensorFlow-gpu na versão 2.0 ou 2.1 (evite instalar versões beta).
3. Python 3.7 como principal do ambiente de desenvolvimento.
4. Configuração dos PATHs do projeto.

Caso todos esses passos tenham sido seguidos provavelmente o seu erro deve sumir.

Como esse post é antigo provavelmente o problema deve ter sido resolvido, caso outra pessoa tenha o mesmo problema, tente executar essas etapas, caso não consiga, tente explicar mais detalhadamente oque tentou executar para o erro surgir.